# Understanding finding the Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am having trouble understanding how to find a Laurent series.
$$\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}(z-c)^{n}$$
where $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f(w)}{(w-c)^{n+1}}dw$, and $C$ is any circle with center $c$.

> I am currently trying to solve the following problem:
>
> Find Laurent series, about the given point $z=-2$, of $$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$$
> Hint: let $z+2=u$

I am trying to find help starting this problem and understanding Laurent series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint yields
$$\frac{u-2}{(u-1)u}=\frac{2}{u}+\frac{1}{1-u}=2u^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n.$$
Now substitute $u=z+2$ to obtain
$$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}=2(z+2)^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n.$$

Comment: So how did you do that once you substituted u?

Comment: The first step is partial fraction decomposition. The second step is geometric series.